# Access Denied while connecting to External Rest API from SharePoint Designer page

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

While trying to connect external Restful API from my SharePoint designer page (On Premises) I am getting access denied error may be its because its cross domain but now I am getting No "Transport error".Last time I had the same situation to i ran some power shell command(3 Line) which i got from website in which they enable cross site scripting for web application if possible can someone send me that script again like below.

```
spwebapp = get-spwebapplication
spwebapp = enable/allow.crosssite
spwebapp.update
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that power shell command modify the file

```
xmlhttprequest
```